# Getting Call to undefined method Yii::app() within layout view

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I've recently started using `Yii 2` and I'm having some issues with the layout file with getting the below error:

```
Call to undefined method Yii::app()
```

This is my layout file:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

?>

<?php $this->beginPage() ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?=Yii::$app->language?>">
<head>
    <title><?=Html::encode($this->title)?></title>
    <meta charset="<?=Yii::$app->charset?>"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?=Html::csrfMetaTags()?>
    <link href="<?=Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="<?=Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">



    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/scripts.js"></script>

    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <script src="<?=Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?=Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <?php $this->head() ?>

</head>
<body>

<?php $this->beginBody() ?>

<?=$content?>

<?php $this->endBody() ?>

</body>
</html>

<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

When I use `Yii::$app` I get no issues, but if I use `Yii::app()` then I get that error.

I started using `Yii::app()` in some places as I was reading around and was told you should use the below to make sure to include *absolute* path names within views:

```
Yii::app()->request->baseUrl
```

...and to include jQuery use:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript("jquery");
```

However when I do anything with `app()` I get the above error.

I tried replacing `app()` with `$app`; the page loaded fine but there was a blank value in `Yii::$app->request->baseUrl`.

What am I doing wrong here!?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Yii 2, `$app` is a property of Yii, not a method, so you should use `Yii::$app->blah`.

[Source](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/59615-getting-call-to-undefined-method-yiiapp-within-layout-view/page__view__findpost__p__267237)

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;`

`Yii::$app` is the static var for the Yii2 Application class, 'yii\web\Application'. It refers to an an instance of the Yii Application class. Since the `Request` class is a configured as an application component by default you have access to the tons of useful properties: [Request Class Reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html)

Yii2 also comes with a bunch of helper classes that do many of the same things: [BaseUrl Helper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html)

Usage is: `Url::base();` ...be sure to use the namespace by placing `use yii\helpers\Url;` at the top of your controller (below the main namespace).

Comment: You might want to explain why this would work.  Code only answers are regarded as low quality and tend to be voted down and closed.

Comment: Updated with explanation.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score -1):

```
Yii::$app->homeUrl
```

`Yii::$app` is the static variable for the Yii2 Application class, 'yii\web\Application'. It refers to an instance of the Yii Application class. Since the `request` class is configured as an application component, by default you have access to all the useful properties.